# computing a derive column in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis, expression

Hi I need help in computing the same value in SSIS expression

```
DATEDIFF (ss,'1960-01-01', DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

which in sql gives me a value of **1803340800**

I tried something like this in SSIS but getting a different value like
**20872.000**

```
DATEDIFF ("ss",(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"01/01/1960", 
DATEADD("dd", DATEDIFF("dd", (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"01/01/1960", GETDATE()),
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"01/01/1960"))
```

Am i doing something wrong novice in SSIS

Comment: Sorry, performing the second expression in SSIS variable I have the same result: 1803340800.

Comment: ok after deriving it i am doing a data conversion task where i convert that column to DT_NUMERIC does this cause the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did copy/paste those two expressions into my environments, SSMS 2016 and VS.NET 2013 Shell (Int32 variable). For both I get 1803340800...

Maybe there's some additional expression because 20872.000 you get when you divide 1803340800 with seconds in one day:

```
1803340800 / 86400 = 20872
```

Comment: sorry it was my wrong i have put ss instead of dd in the expression..ty for ur help